# Angular 2 opening different pages on click of nav menu but without changing the URL

Tags: angular

In angular 2 I would like to implement menu in such a way that it does not change the URL but opens different pages. I was initially trying with angular2 router, but it was showing different URLs with the router links , is there any way to not change the URL while loading different pages on click on menu tabs.

Comment: If you want an answer show your question with your code and/or images,

Comment: @MayankSingh is correct, you should include code/images in your question to help identify what your exact problem is and what's causing the issue. It does sound like what you're trying to attempt is deep linkin. You have a spa with a main URI lets say '/home' and you have internal navigation inside of this page which is changed when selecting a navigation element. you might want to visit https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 for an idea on who to achieve deep linking

Comment: Please put some codes, so that it's easy to understand the scenario, and we can help

Answer (score 1):

### Possible solution-

### tab.component.html

```
<ul class=" nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
    <li class="tab-link" *ngFor="let tab of tabsdata;let i = index;let frst=first" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(100% /' + tabsdata.length + ')'}">
        <a (click)="tabsUL($event);" href="#tab-{{i+1}}" role="tab">{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### tab.component.ts

```
tabsdata = ['tab0', 'tab1'];
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.activeTab('tab-1');     // set active tabcontent as 'tab-1';
      }

    tabsUL(event): void {
        let tab_id = event.target.hash.replace('#', '');
        this.activeTab(tab_id);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      activeTab(id) {
        let tabsEl = this.tabs.nativeElement;
        this.removeActive(tabsEl.querySelectorAll('.active'));
        this.setActive([
          tabsEl.querySelector(`#${id}`),
          tabsEl.querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`).parentNode
        ]);

      }

      setActive(elems) {
        elems.forEach((el) => {
          el.className += ' active';
        });
      }

      removeActive(elems) {
        elems.forEach((el) => {
          el.className = el.className.replace(' active', '');
        });
```

### tab.component.css

```
--------------------
 .tabs {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
}

.navMenu {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #777;
} 


 .tablist {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tablist .tab-link {
    display: inline-block;
}

.tablist .tab-link a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tablist .tab-link a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tablist .tab-link.active a {
    background: #ededed;
    color: #fff;
}


 .tab-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.tab-content.active {
  background: #ededed;
 display: block; 
 }
```